# How do I remove RangeIndex and dtypes from output display?

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas

**OUTPUT DISPLAY-** [This is the output of my program project and only thing is remaining is that RangeIndex and dtypes values which I can't able to remoe from output display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPWJX.png)

**SOURCE CODE-** I are working on python project and narrow down the problem in my code which is below, you can see that between hello1 and hello2 and this the first 20 line of my code.

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


def train_data():

    # Read data
    data = pd.read_csv("crop_csv_file_csv.csv");
    # Print column names to identify the correct target column name!
    print('hello1');
    data.head();
    data.head();
    data = data[:10000];
    data.head();
    data.info(verbose=False)
    print('hello2');
```

Following are the things, I tried -

```
1. data.to_csv(header=None,index=False)
2. data.to_csv(index=False)
3. data = pandas.read_csv('crop_csv_file_csv.csv', header=None)
4. tried to remove all 3 data.head()
```

Whenever I tried the above things, no output is displayed and i get a blank display.

Comment: Your question is not complete by any means.  You are showing us a browser window from a PHP script.  This is not a PHP script.  The output you see is from the two `print` statements and the `data.info` call.  What on earth are you expecting?  What do you WANT?  `data.head` does not print anything.

Comment: And, by the way, Python statements do not use semicolons.  That's a bad habit leftover from PHP.

Comment: @TimRoberts , sorry for incomplete question - i want to remove/ hide that dtypes and rangeindex  from output display ( i only want crop yield prediction:  ). should i put my whole python script for reference !

Comment: THIS code is not printing the "crop yield prediction" line, so we can't tell where that comes from.  You can delete everything after the `read_csv` to get rid of the extra output.

Comment: @TimRoberts where-ever i tried to delete `data.head()` to `data.info(verbose=False)` my system is crashing and whole system became super slow.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanking you for your time to reply . My issue just got solved by removing the `data.info()` code. Can you tell me **"How to read and process large csv file of 50000 entries."**

Comment: 50,000 lines is not that large.  Perhaps it is time for a different question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community My problem has resolved!!